# Identityserver4 two different clients in one browser

Tags: cookies, identityserver4

I have two web-application hosted on different url:

- http://app-atc.team.in (web-application1)
- http://app-mbq.team.in (web-application2)

For authentication they use common identity server, but use angular-oauth2-oidc with different clientId of identityserver: -client1, clinet2.

If i login in web-application1, then i try to enter web-application2 - the identity server automatically authorizes in web-application2 as the same user as in application1. This only applies to a single browser. In different browsers, I can login in web-application1 with one user and web-application2 with another user. How to make such a behavior in one browser?

As I understood - in one browser web-applications link to the same cookies. Possible solution on the identityserver to create cookies with the names contains clientId - for example: idsrv.session.client1, .AspNetCore.Identity.Application.client1 etc. How to do it on the identityserver or is there another solution?[image]

Comment: is you sure of properly config your client id on client side?where your client send request to server to different client id,so there are different claim(your client id) for any connected client to identity server.

Comment: what you are trying to reach is to adapt single sign on technology to "local sign on" architecture. the simplest seems to be getting rid of IdSrv at all and use local login form inside each app.

Comment: @ivanof81 did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the Identity Server 4 cookie authentication scheme. You could override it with a scheme which sets cookie to expire almost immediately after being issued. This will effectively remove the single sign-on behaviour from the central login part.

```
services.AddIdentityServer()...

//Call it after AddIdentityServer
services.AddAuthentication("MyCookie")
    .AddCookie("MyCookie", options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = 1;
    });
```

More info about sign in behaviour at [Identity Server docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html).

Comment: I wrote this in Startup.cs of  identityserver — this did not solve the problem. Is it possible to completely disable cookie authentication for identityserver?

Comment: @ivanof81 try using `IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme` instead of `MyCookie`. And can you check what cookies you have and how long they last after you've done it.

Answer (score 0):

To force the login on every visit to the authorize endpoint you can use the ‘prompt’ query string with the value set to ‘login’. This way you don’t have to mess with the cookie auth and increase the complexity within your code base.

More info can be found in my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54672252/7407434